# How to make a network printer available for DOS in VirtualBox?

Tags: networking, printing, freedos

I have a network printer, which supports PostScript directly. This printer has a logical printer port at 192.168.1.23:9100 and I can confirm works well.

Now, I have a FreeDOS 1.2 in a VirtualBox VM, and I'd like to print on that network printer from within DOS.

In the VM settings, I can only set COM ports, LPT doesn't seem to be available. However I've failed to make the VM use the remote printer and port as serial port interface.

I'm not sure how I should proceed from here.

Host OS is Fedora 25.

Comment: Have you tried printer.sys? http://help.fdos.org/en/hhstndrd/base/printer.htm

Comment: And, if you're printing from DOS, remember that PostScript will *not* print plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to VirtualBox myself, but I have managed to get XP to talk to a  printer that is located on another machine on the network.

First of all, I believe your VM must have network capability. I'm not familiar with FreeDos, so I can't help with that.

In VirtualBox, You need to enable your network adapter to see your network.
In the VBox manager, select your virtual machine and click Settings.
Open the Network section
Under Adapter 1, check "Enable Network Adapter"
"Attached to:" Bridged adapter
"Name:" use the name of your host network adapter
Expand the "Advanced" section
"Adapter Type:" Start with "PCnet-FASTIII"
"Promiscuous mode:" Deny (Default)
If you are hardwired to the network, check "Cable Connected"

Test to see if your VM can see other machines on the network.
If not, check your firewall to see if the Virtualbox Virtual Machines are allowed access to the network.

I'm printing stuff from DOS mode under XP.  To make this work, I used the command:
NET USE LPT1:\Servername\Printername

This is what it took for me.  Hope it helps you.